# R - Regression error due to apparently 1 factorial variables

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have the following data set:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdbfp8dx2fstz6w/ames_train.Rdata?dl=0

In a project I am supposed to find the best linear model. To be save, I wanted to make sure that I do not leave out anything significant, so I included all variables and wanted to backward eliminated them based on p-values etc.

However, when I for instance run:

```
firstreg = lm(price ~ ., data = (ames_train))
```

or

```
bestmod=bas.lm(price ~ ., data=ames_train, prior="BIC", modelprior = uniform())
```

I get

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  i contrasti si possono applicare solo a variabili factor con 2 o più livelli
```

I do not understand the issue here though, because I tested it and none of the variables seems to have only 1 factor:

```
l=sapply(ames_train, function(x) is.factor(x))
m <- ames_test[, l]
ifelse(n <- sapply(m, function(x) length(levels(x))) == 1, "DROP", "NODROP")
```

I probably overlook something trivial but I am a bit stuck. Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: `Utilities` has only one level present in the data, and there's not a single row without missing data. You can replicate the error your getting as follows: `lm(price ~ ., data = data.frame(price=1:10, x=rep(c("A",NA),20), y=rep(c(NA,"B",NA,"C"),10)))`. The data frame has missing data in every row and one of the predictor columns has only one level present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lm` will remove rows where a column in the model is `NA`. If you include all possible columns (which is statistically a terrible strategy anyway, and doubly so with the large amount of predictors and factor levels), it will drop all rows where at least one observation is missing, i.e. the result of `na.omit(ames_test)`. As you can see, this leaves you with not a single observation in the data set.

As a first step, remove those columns from the model that have a lot of NAs.